# Get MD5 Checksum of online file before download in VB

Tags: vb.net, hash

I have a website that has the old "list files" style of doing things, and I want to perform a hash on a file there before downloading it to the user's local system. I know how to hash a local file, but it seems there's not a lot of info as to whether or not I can do this without downloading the online file. My logic is, if the user already has the same file, why waste time downloading it? So, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Hashing a file requires having the file contents, which requires downloading the file, i.e. no it is not possible to do that.

Comment: So, my followup question is then, how do other programs achieve file comparison to online repositories if not with a checksum? Surely they don't download every file to check it.

Comment: Often times, those providing the files will also provide checksums separately. In my experience, that's normally for the purposes of verifying a file after download but it could also be used for your purpose. You could also use a last update date, but that might not work if the local file had been manipulated.

Comment: I had it using the date before, but it wasn't working. Only just now I have realized my other mistake I made, and I think date modified might be working correctly again. I think I'm going to use this date modified aspect, but also give users the opportunity to wipe the slate and start over should they accidentally or otherwise modify a file. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further contemplation I decided that the date modified comparison is actually the behavior that I want. If a client were to modify a file on accident, there is now an option to correct it. If they modify it on purpose, I certainly don't want to wipe out their work.